# facebook all Taggable Friends list got null data after submit my apps to facebook review?

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

i want to get all friend list from Facebook . i am use Facebook version 3.14 SDK . but i got always null data after call Facebook API.

```
/* make the API call */
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/taggable_friends"
                             parameters:nil
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(
                          FBRequestConnection *connection,
                          id result,
                          NSError *error
                      ) {
                          /* handle the result */
                      }];
```

And Its Permission also give `user_friends`

I am also put my apps in Facebook Review but i have got alert as below.[image]